# Where does the micrometer publish metrics as <metricName>_seconds_bucket, <metricName>_seconds_count and <metricName>_seconds_sum?

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer, prometheus-java

The Micrometer produces metrics such as

```
metric_name_seconds_bucket{tags,le="+Inf",} 1.0
metric_name_seconds_count{tags,} 1.0
metric_name_seconds_sum{tags,} 0.256
```

for all metrics. Where does Micrometer produces this metrics in code?

I want to extend this metrics with my own.
For example I want to see

```
metric_name_seconds_bucket{tags,le="+Inf",} 1.0
metric_name_seconds_count{tags,} 1.0
metric_name_seconds_sum{tags,} 0.256

metric_name_seconds_mean{tags}
metric_name_seconds_throughput{tags}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I can override this io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry#addDistributionStatisticSamples

[This place where metrics created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWpUc.png)